# Genitive of masculine plural indefinite nouns: -n ending

Tags: noun, gender, genitive, grammatical-number, definite-article

Compare:

```
              Plural definite:    Plural indefinite:

Nominativ:    die Äpfel           Äpfel
Genitiv:      der Äpfel           Äpfel
Dativ:        den Äpfeln          Äpfeln
Akkusativ:    die Äpfel           Äpfel
```

[http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Äpfel](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=%C3%84pfel)

```
              Plural definite:    Plural indefinite:
Nominativ:    die Männer          Männer
Genitiv:      der Männer          Männern <-- THIS
Dativ:        den Männern         Männern
Akkusativ:    die Männer          Männer
```

http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Mann

**Why does *Männer* acquire an *-n* ending in the indefinite genitive, but *Äpfel* doesn't?**

**May 17**
The error was not in the source. Take a look at this link: http://www.welt.de/vermischtes/article3011942/Wenn-Frauen-toeten-dann-oft-wegen-der-Maenner.html

wegen is a preposition that always takes the genitive. In the title the definite plural form (wegen der Männer) is used, but later in the article the indefinite plural form (wegen Männern) is used.

I'd still very much like an explanation of why the definite and indefinite forms differ in this case, as I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Could you please add the source where you found these declination tables? I followed your links but couldn't find them.

Comment: This seems wrong to me.

Comment: @boaten, da ist links neben dem Abspielicon für die Aussprache noch ein weiteres Icon, das vielleicht ein Buch oder eine Tabelle symbolisiert.

Comment: @CarstenS Ah, danke.

Comment: @boaten, ich musste auch suchen.

Comment: The only indefinitive plural expressing ownership (i.e at least genitive-like) I can think of is "von Männern" - but "von" wants the dative. Maybe "Männerhosen" fits, but that's a composite.  I'm not even sure that case exists.... I'd like to see an example sentence if anyone has one.

Comment: @tofro „Männer Hosen“ ;)

Comment: Those Männerhosen do /not/ fit ;)

Comment: When would you use that form anyway? "Ich gedenke der Männer" - "Ich gedenke Männer[n]"? -" Ich bedarf der Männer" - "Ich bedarf Männer[n]". They all sound weird anyway, but probably more so because the genitive is getting out of fashion.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language StackExchange. If you want, you can take the [tour] or take a look at the [help]. Have fun!

Comment: About your May-17-edit: »der Männer« in »wegen der Männer« is dative case, not genitive. It is »wegen mir«, not »wegen meiner«. The word »wegen« does **not** always take the genitive case! It is genitive case in »wegen meiner Frau«. Same in englisch: correct: "because of me" (wegen mir; wegen der Männer). wrong: "because of my" (wegen meiner; wegen der Männer). correct: "because of my wife" (wegen meiner Frau; wegen der Männer Frauen). But the construction "wegen der Männer Frauen" is weird because most people will (wrongly) interpret »der Männer« as dative, and then »Frauen« does not mix.

Comment: See https://german.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for how to merge your two accounts into one.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: I'm not quite sure what you are referring to, but _wegen der Männer_ ist of course not dative but genitive; the dative would be _wegen den Männern_. The only way to interprete _wegen der Männer Frauen_ can be _because of the men's wives_, since _der Männer_ cannot be dative. It is a preceding genitive attribute and  works like a definite article, but that sort of construction is outdated and hard to understand. Nowadays nobody would say _meines Vaters Brüder_. Combined with _wegen_ you get _wegen meines Vaters Brüdern_, the genitive 'Brüder' would be incorrect here.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn’t; it’s an error in your source. Canoonet, e.g., [correctly has *Männer*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/mann:N:M:er).

---

Regarding your addition of *wegen Männern*: The problem here is in your assumption that “*wegen* is a preposition that always takes the genitive”. This is wrong; in fact, the dative is arguably more common in spoken language, and there are certain cases where dative is used even in standard language, of which this is one. See again Canoonet for [the details](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html?lang=en#Anchor-wegen-58500).

Comment: The question concerns *indefinite* nouns though. (I agree with you, but your link doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: Is the indefinite plural form ever different from the definite one?

Comment: @Carsten S: Only for adjectives-turned-nouns, such as _Angestellter_ (_die Angestellten_, _einige Angestellte_).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I do have the answer now. The genitive indefinite plural of Mann is indeed Männer and not Männern, but the dative is used instead when the genitive is not apparent (die Autos Männern, not die Autos Männer). The same with Äpfel.

Leo was at fault here. The entries for Mann, Wald and Gott all give the dative instead of the genitive form in indefinite plural.

Comment: What is "die Autos Männern" supposed to mean?

Comment: But then it is "wegen Äpfeln" too or "wegen Kindern" or "wegen Dampfschifffahrern", et cetera. That concerns **all** nouns meaning, you have to use the _Dative_, when you work with "_wegen_" in the _indefinite plural_, though in other cases you **do** use the **Genitive**. - - - Also "Die Autos Männern" means nothing, you **need** a definite article here!

Answer (score 2):

In German, we have a [**Genitivregel**](http://homepages.uni-jena.de/~x1gape/Wort/Wort_NP_Genitiv.pdf) saying that the Genitive has to be recognizable either by the noun's or the article's (determiner's) or the adjective's ending. Plural nouns like *Männer* don't have a distinct genitive ending, the only distinct plural ending is **-n** for the dative *Männern*. So if you want to use *Männer* in the genitive you have to mark the genitive

- by an article (determiner): *die Autos **mancher** Männer*
- or by an adjective: *(die) Autos **französischer** Männer*

which is grammatically correct (but strange as an idea).

For syntactic or semantic reasons it is often not possible to add an article or an adjective, then you must construct your idea in another way, e.g. as a *von*-construction.

---

Ich empfehle die Lektüre des verlinkten Aufsatzes. Dort findet sich eine ausführliche syntaktische Diskussion der Genitivregel inklusive einer umfangreichen Liste von Ausweichkonstruktionen. Vor dem Hintergrund dieser Regel sind Tabellen, in denen Genitivformen von Substantiven ohne deutlichen hinweis darauf, dass diese Formen nicht isoliert verwendet werden dürfen, irreführend. Das gilt, soweit ich sehe, für alle artikellosen Genitiv-Pluralformen, denn eine separate Genitiv-Plural-Endung der Nomina haben wir im Deutschen nicht.

Comment: Good answer, except that _viele_ is not an article. You could change the first example into _die Autos der Männer_.

Comment: @chirlu: I didn't want to give an example with a 'classical' article in order to bring to mind that there are many more 'articles' than _der, die, das_ and _ein/e_. 'Viele' may be interpreted as a 'Quantifikativ-Artikel', but from a morphemic point of view it is declined like an adjective. As I don't want to discuss this point here I replace _vieler_ by _mancher_.